# Spring Boot app. Logger doesn't log DEBUG messages

Tags: java, logging, spring-boot, slf4j

I have application.yml with the following lines:

```
logging:
    file: logs/keyserver.log
    level:
        org.springframework.web: 'DEBUG'
```

It works ok except this case:

```
public class TransactionBuilder extends Wallet {

    private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TransactionBuilder.class);

    @Override
    public RedeemData findRedeemDataFromScriptHash(byte[] payToScriptHash) {
        LOG.debug("payToScriptHash = " + HEX.encode(payToScriptHash));
    }

}
```

The messages is appeared neither in log file nor on the screen.

However

```
LOG.info("payToScriptHash = " + HEX.encode(payToScriptHash));
LOG.error("payToScriptHash = " + HEX.encode(payToScriptHash));
```

works just fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume that your class `TransactionBuilder` is not in the `org.springframework.web` package. Just add your package to the logging section of your configuration:

```
logging:
    file: logs/keyserver.log
    level:
        org.springframework.web: 'DEBUG'
        your.package: 'DEBUG'
```